# Choosing colors appropriately for red-green colorblindness

Tags: color, color-blindness

I want a green for "correct answer" and a red for "wrong answer". My current choice is `rgb(144, 238, 144)` for the green and `rgb(250, 128, 114)` for the red. (See wikilearner.net/wiki for the colours in action.)

I have been told that these colors are very close in contrast, making it difficult for a person with red-green color-blindness. What would be a better choice?

Comment: FWIW, I have moderate red-green color-blindness. The colors you have on that page look just fine to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever I have concerns about colour contrasts/accessibility for colour blindness, I head over here: http://www.visionaustralia.org.au/info.aspx?page=628.

Steve Faulkner's Colour Contrast Analyser has been eternally helpful to me.

Answer (score 5):

it's always good practise to not simply depend singularly on colour to differentiate between states.
perhaps incorporate symbol or shape into your design.
try this very very practical tool to ensure you have enough differentiation between the two states.
http://www.vischeck.com/

cheers

Answer (score 4):

There are various tools available that simulate colour blindness.  I would suggest trying this site: http://www.vischeck.com/

Also it is good practice regards accessibility to not rely on colour alone:

WCAG 2.0 - 1.4.1 - Color is not used as the sole method of conveying content or distinguishing visual elements.